# Set property gives value in one method but in another method it says NULL

Tags: php

I am trying to set a property and have it available in multiple classes. I set the property and echo it from the method it is set in and it give the set value but when I use `var_dump` from another method then it says that it is null. Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong? The output is `BLAHNULL` Thanks in advance

```
Class Process {

    public $failed;

    public function setFailed($failed) {
        $this->failed = $failed;
        echo $this->failed;
    }


    public function showFailed() {
        $geocode = new Geocode;
        $geocode->geoCodeAddress();
        var_dump($this->failed);
    }
}

Class Geocode {
    public function geoCodeAddress() {
        $process = new Process;
        $process->setFailed('BLAH');
    }
}

$test = new Process;
$test->showFailed();
```

Comment: What methods are you using?

Comment: What you see it the entire code I am trying to run in a single php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting "BLAH" to $process->failed, and trying to echo $test->failed.

$process is not the same instance as $test.
Whatever you do to $process, $test has no access to it.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think what you want is a class extension:

```
Class Process extends Geocode{
    public function showFailed() {
        $this->setFailed('BLAH');
    }
}

Class Geocode{
    public $failed;

    public function setFailed($failed) {
        $this->failed = $failed;
        echo $this->failed;
    }
}

$test = new Process;
$test->showFailed();
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not attach your output, but I'm assumping it looks something like this: `BLAHNULL`

The `$failed` variable is an instance variable. It is different for each "Process" you make.

When you call showFailed, it makes a geocode, which in turn makes a new Process. That process then echoes its `BLAH` status after being set. Once that geoCodeAddress exits, the failed status of the original, outer Process is printed, which is null.